# How to set a timer that do something after it finishes in an activity with button that if clicked something else happens?

Tags: java, android

I have an activity in my android app that shows a word to the user. if the user could guess the answer in less than 60 seconds he would press a button and go to another activity. but if he could not do it and the time finishes, a third activity must show. How should I do it? with threading or timer or something like that?

I have tried threading but the app crashes.

Comment: the question in question tag is not clear to me with what happens and what should be done. Please rephrase. Also, post your code so we can have a look at the threading issue and perhaps help on that?

Comment: @ZF007 . I'm new here and I don't know how to edit my question. I searched for an edit button or something like that but I could not find any. I accept your your comment and it is because of my week English. Although I have find the solution thank to william xyz. I also thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using Handler.

**Kotlin**

```
// declare this variables as attributes in you class
val handler = Handler()
val runnable = Runnable {
    // Call something when it finishes
}
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 60_000) // Do something after 60 seconds


// and if you want to cancel the timer, you can cancel it this way
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
```

**Java**

```
// declare this variables as attributes in you class
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Call something when it finishes
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 60_000);

// and if you want to cancel the timer, you can cancel it this way
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Comment: That worked really well! Thank you very much William.